# DHIS2: Category Options Missing

Tags: dhis-2

I have a category AGE it has Category options (<1y,1-4y,5-9y,9-15y), Gender(Male,Female) I have created a category combination AGE+GENDER.

My issue is when i add a new AGE seggragation like 15-20y it does not appear in the data elements segregation.

Please Help